# Question about nodes

Tags: ros, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a question about how nodes are implemented in ROS. From what I understand the "type=" definition refers to an executable file that ROS runs. Consider this example:

Now when I go into the robot_state package I don't find an executable called robot_state_publisher. Would anyone care to explain why that is?

Regards,
Devin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219991/question-about-nodes/) by [TheDude35](https://answers.ros.org/users/23839/thedude35/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2015-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right, `type="<EXECUTABLE>"`.

The `robot_state_publisher` is defined in the `robot_state_publisher` package (not `robot_state`, this is just a name for the node).
However, if you install executables from apt-get (or build them yourself), they don't end up in the package, but in `/opt/ros/<DISTRO>/lib/<PACKAGE>/<EXECUTABLE>` (or `<CATKIN_WS>/../devel/lib/<PACKAGE>/<EXECUTABLE>` if you compile it yourself).

However, nodes need to be implemented in a special way. Check out [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) for a simple example. Make sure to read the in-source comments.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheDude35](https://answers.ros.org/users/23839/thedude35/) on 2015-10-27**:
Makes sense now thanks gentlemen

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The executables are not stored directly in the package directories. They are stored in a "lib" directory. Try "ls /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/lib/robot_state_publisher" and the executable "robot_state_publisher" should be in there.

This is also the case in your catkin workspace. When you do "catkin_make", it doesn't place each executable in its corresponding package's directory. It places them in the "devel/lib/" folders of your catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) with karma: 380 on 2015-10-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-10-27**:
whoops. almost simultaneously ;-)

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2015-10-27**:
I didn't refresh before submitting my answer, whoops! So close.